# Curvature of curve

Tags: integration, parametric, curvature

$r(t) = (-3sint)i + (-3sint)j + (cost)k$

I got as far as:$$||r'(u)|| = sqrt{(18cos^2u + sin^2u)}$$

But I cannot evaluate $\int_0^t||r'(u)||dt$

Comment: What are you trying to calculate ? Please be clearer as to your question.

Comment: I stated that in the title ... The curvature   my apologies

Comment: what does that have to do with the integral ?

Comment: what do u mean ... first I have to re parametrize the curve in terms of the arc length ... that is where the integral comes into play

Comment: Oh I see, most often it is to difficult to calculate the arc length parameterizations, the integrals cannot be evaluated in elementary terms. There is a curvature formula which is valid for any parameterization, you must have it in your textbook.

Comment: Hnmn,  does it have a particular name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parametrizing by arc-length is not so easy in this question. Instead, use the formula $$\kappa(t)=\frac{|r^\prime(t)\times r^{\prime\prime}(t)|}{|r^\prime(t)|^3}$$

Comment: Yes that is it, I was just about to type it out.

Comment: i get a final answer of $18/((18cos^2(t) + sin^2(t))^{(3/2)})$

Can someone please confirm this